# Update Columns Where The Parameter Has Been Supplied From Code

Tags: .net, sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am going to be executing an Update stored procedure from .NET. I want the following logic in T-SQL, however I can't seem to find out how this can be done.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateTable

    @TableID int,
    @StartTime1 datetime,
    @EndTime1 datetime

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [Table]
       SET [StartTime1] = WAS_PASSED_FROM_CODE(@StartTime1, @StartTime1, [StartTime1])
          ,[EndTime1]   = WAS_PASSED_FROM_CODE(@EndTime1,   @EndTime1,   [EndTime1])
    WHERE TableID = @TableID
END
GO
```

Okay, so what I am basically looking for is a way to determine whether the parameter was specified from code, (hence WAS_PASSED_FROM_CODE) if the parameter was specified from code, then update that column to the specified value, else, leave intact (update to existing value).

Is this possible?

Note that in this case it is valid for the code to pass NULL, in that case, the column should update to NULL.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has reserved that prefix for its own use, and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I don't know about 2008+ but sp_ will also has performance ramifications as well.  http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/

Comment: So, are you asking for help in writing the function WAS_PASSED_FROM_CODE?  You may have to specify dbo.WAS_PASSED_FROM_CODE.

Comment: @sam yi

Yes, if such a function can be created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your parameters default to `NULL` and then use `ISNULL`.  If the parameter is not specified it will be `NULL`

Edit: Given that NULL is a valid value, add two additional parameters to marked whether or not the date parameters are specified.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateTable

    @TableID int,
    @StartTime1 datetime,
    @StartTime1Specified BIT,
    @EndTime1 datetime,
    @EndTime1Specified BIT

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [Table]
       SET [StartTime1] = (CASE WHEN @StartTime1Specified = 1 THEN @StartTime1 ELSE [StartTime1] END)
          ,[EndTime1]   = (CASE WHEN @EndTime1Specified = 1 THEN @EndTime1 ELSE [EndTime1])
    WHERE TableID = @TableID
END
GO
```

Comment: I can't think of a better way. I think the only options are to use a sentinel value such as `NULL` or if no such value exists as the entire domain of values is potentially valid then to use a separate parameter to indicate "ischanged"

Comment: Actually there may be valid cases where null will be specified by the code, this is where my issue comes from. I have edited my post to reflect that I would need to handle this case.

Comment: @reedparkes Updated answer to handle NULL being a valid value by adding two additional parameters that indicate if the dates are specified.  Then use a case statement in the update based on that value

Comment: I will mark it as the answer, I knew I could do this but was hoping for some magical SQL function that I hadn't heard of.